# docker-compose: access backend service "internally" via Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, backend, docker-container

My objectives are the following:

1. Access frontend (Angular) app globally via `localhost:80`
2. Access backend (Express) app only "internally" (not `localhost:3000`) via frontend app

My `docker-compose.yml` file content is below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: front-container
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    build: api
    container_name: back-container
    restart: always
```

Comment: Is the Angular app ultimately running in a browser?  Or do you have a server-side app running in a container, that you’ve implemented using Angular?

Comment: Hi Ziyaddin, I am facing the same issue and tried various things but Angular doesn't seem to work with the reference container. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi Konstantinos. As I had little time, I went with having independent machine in local network for backend and connecting through independent IP address. So, I didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

My understanding of Docker compose and networking is that with the services defined as you have, you can access the API via the hostname `api`.

I imagine you'll also want to expose port 3000 on the API service so that you can access it.

Then from your frontend app you can make requests to `api:3000/endpoint/to/call`

Comment: I have already tried that, no success. Should it be `http://api:3000` or just `api:3000`?

Comment: Can you give more info on what you tried and why it has failed, please ? Does your api container start without error when you do `docker-compose up` ?

Comment: Have you tried dropping into the `app` container and probing the `api` service yourself? That's what I would try.

Comment: You need to expose the API. Clients using angular app on their browser are outside the server machine and thus any call made to API from there needs to go to a valid API endpoint. To do so, API needs to be exposed. If everything is happening on the server side then you can just use the service name to communicate but as per the problem you have described, exposing API is required.